# Stylesheets load but are empty on page refresh in nested state

Tags: css, angularjs, node.js

I'm having an issue where if I refresh the page in a state that is nested in my AngularJS app, the browser shows that my stylesheets were loaded, but they are empty for some reason. I am using ui-router. There are no errors in my console. I am not sure if this has anything to do with the server, but I am using NodeJS with LoopBack framework.

View my issue [here](http://70.78.5.204:3000/portfolio/tempostorm)

If you navigate to one of the top-level states and refresh the page, the styles will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a domain relative url for your stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
```

This will load your stylesheet from http://70.78.5.204:3000/css/styles.css

Comment: oh boy, thank you! I thought using `./` would make the path relative, but I just needed `/` before the path.